# How to calculate the expected values (entry*index) of a tensor for each index

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `t = {t[0], t[1], ..., t[m]}` . For each element `i` in this tensor, I would like to calculate `t[i]*i`, which will result in a new tensor `t'` with the same shape, and the following values: `t' = {t[0]*0, t[1]*1, ..., t[m]*m}`.

How can I implement this?
I have tried using a for loop, but it failed, as the following error was raised.

```
TypeError: `Tensor` objects are not iterable when eager execution is not 
enabled. To iterate over this tensor use `tf.map_fn`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`tf.range`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range). E.g.

```
res = tf.range(t.shape[0]) * t
```

Answer (score 0):

You have actually answered what I have asked, put in fact, I have a more general problem.

There is a three dimensional tensor, which I need to compute the expected values for the elements of the second dimension. I have tried to do it through a for-loop like below, but the error 'tensor is not iterable' has been raised.

```
for i in tf.range(start=0, limit=softed_mul.shape[0]):
    elems = (softed_mul[i, :, :], indexs)
    softed_arg_maxs[i, :, :] = tf.map_fn(lambda x:x[0] * x[1], elems, 
    dtype=tf.float32)
```